# Initialize a class with brace-enclosed initializer list

Tags: c++, c++14, initializer-list

I'm trying to initialize a class Vec with a brace-enclosed initializer list, to be called like in this minimal example:

```
int main()
{
    Vec<3> myVec1{{1,2,3}}; // or: myVec1({1,2,3});
    Vec<3> myVec2;
    myVec2 = {1, 2, 3};
    Vec<3> myVec3 = {1,2,3};
    return 0;
}
```

All these initializations (and the assignment) should work. (Plus custom default constructor. Using an aggregate class is thus impossible.)

While I could just use a std::initializer_list like such:

```
template <unsigned C>
struct Vec
{
    Vec(){}
    Vec(std::initializer_list<int> list)
    {
        //does not work for obvious reasons:
        //static_assert(list.size() == C, "");
    }
};
```

I can't statically ensure the number of parameters to be equal to my template parameter, i.e., an initialization with {1, 2, 3, 4} would only fail during runtime.

Browsing SO, I came up with the following:

```
template <unsigned C>
struct Vec
{
    Vec(){}
    Vec(const unsigned(&other)[C]){}
    Vec& operator=(const unsigned(&other)[C]){return *this;}
};
```

This works fine for the assignment and () or {} initialization (as for myVec1) - but it fails for the initialization using = (as for myVec3).

(GCC gives error "could not convert '{1, 2, 3}' from '' to 'Vec<3u>'")

I don't get why one of the initializations should work, but not the other.
Any other ideas how I can use the brace-enclosed initializer list, but also ensure the correct length at compile time?

Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe variadic templates with a static_assert or just sfinae with enable_if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initializer lists are more appropriate for situations where the size of the list is dynamic. In your case, where the size of `Vec` is a template parameter (i.e. static), you're probably better off with variadic parameters:

```
template <unsigned C>
struct Vec
{
    Vec(){}

    template<typename ... V>
    Vec(V ... args)
    {
        static_assert(sizeof...(V) == C, "");
        //...
    }
};
```

then these will work:

```
Vec<3> myVec2;
myVec2 = {1, 2, 3};
Vec<3> myVec3 = {1,2,3};
```

But this one won't, as it explicitly requires an `std::initializer_list`:

```
Vec<3> myVec1{{1,2,3}};
```

Comment: Indeed, with just a little bit of template recursion magic, one can resolve the issue. As you predicted, this call doesn't work any more: `Vec<3> myVec1{{1,2,3}};` - but as it can be replaced by the much more natural `Vec<3> myVec1{1,2,3};`, it's even more preferable.

Answer (score 0):

You need two pair of brackets:

```
Vec<3> myVec3 = {{1,2,3}};
```

When you do:

```
Vec<3> myVec3 = {1, 2, 3};
// It is the same as (except that explicit constructor are not considered):
Vec<3> myVec3 = Vec<3>{1, 2, 3};'
```

So basically, the compiler will look for a constructor for `Vec<3>` which either takes an `std::initializer_list` or a constructor that takes 3 arguments, all of which being constructible from `int`.

If you want a `std::array` like structure, you need to make your type [an aggregate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization), meaning that it should not have user-defined constructor:

```
template <unsigned N>
struct Vec {
  int data[N];
};

void f() {
  Vec<3> v1{{1, 2, 3}};
  Vec<3> v2 = {{1, 2, 3}};
}
```

Comment: @Benjamin I don't know what you are exactly doing but if you are using that kind of stuff in a real project you should go for `std::array`. Variadic templates have great uses, but I am not sure this is one, and I would not use only because it allows you to create array without a double pair of brackets.

Comment: Thanks for casting some light on how the compiler resolves the brackets. The double curly brackets don't seem very natural to me, so I'm inclined to use the variadic template solution instead. Using an aggregate would harm my efforts into creating a class that can be easily converted to from similar classes. Also, I just found out that the brace-enclosed initializer list is padded with default values, making `Vec<3> myVec3 = {{1,2,3,4}};` an error, but `Vec<3> myVec3 = {{1,2}};` not.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up the comment order. The main reason is ease of use, I often initialize `std::vector`s with the ` = {1, 2, 3}` syntax, and I believe other people will try to do so for other classes (such as this). As this constructor will only be called for hardcoded user input, no performance issues should arise. Writing unit tests ATM, it seems that always the correct constructor is chosen; any other reasons speaking against the variadic template way?

Comment: @Benjamin I don't know how compiler optimize this, but using variadic templates means that each value has to be pushed on the stack one by one, so if you have large array, this is a performance issue. Also, people use to `std::array` are used to the `{{ }}` or even anyone using aggregates. The main issue (IMO) is that any C++ programmer will think that `Vec<3> v{1, 2, 3};` uses a `initializer_list` constructor, which is does not if you use the variadic version, so it may be very troubling for anyone familiar with `initializer_list`, much more than `{{1, 2, 3}}`, but again, that's my opinion.